# Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at bundle.js(es-build)

Tags: reactjs, esbuild

I am using an esbuild API build to bundle a basic React app . But it keeps bringing up the following error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at bundle.js`.Below is my `build.js` code.

```js
const esbuild = require('esbuild');

async function build() {
  await esbuild.build({
    entryPoints: ['index.js'],
    outfile: './build/bundle.js',
    format: 'cjs',
    loader: { '.js': 'jsx' },
  });
}

build();
```

What I tried:

- Clearing terminal history.
- Deleting `bundle.js` and regenerating it again
- Restarting vs-code.

Comment: have you tried to change format to `iife` ?

Comment: No, let me try and see if it works .thanks

Comment: Not working . Guess I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the scope of require to the scope where you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `const esbuild = require('esbuild');` with `import esbuild from 'esbuild';` and changed the format to iife. And it worked.